# Appium "Inspector Connection Error"

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium

I wrote a simple test with Appium and it's working.
But now, i want to use the Appium Inspector to be able to find elements to test a mobile website. (i'm not testing a special App, i'm just using the **default browser**).

And this is the error i have:
"Inspector Connection Error"
[image]

I know I can just find the elements in the computer, but i would like to know why I've got this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message it seems the appium server is not running, but your appium server log(partially seen) show that it requires set up the capabilities. To use inspector, it is required to enter the capabilities.

Enter the app path (the path to apk file), package name, app activtiy.

If you are not using any apk file, then run UIAutomatorviewer.bat file located in Andriod sdk folder

Comment: I have no idea where i can find the apk file, i only have .img (Emulation of the android device)

Comment: screenshot shows, you haven't launched the app. Apk fle is your native or hybrid application file that you want test.

Comment: I found out that Appium Inspector is only here to test Apk, if someone want to find elements without any Apk you can use uiautomatorviewer.bat Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah. Inspector require application under test.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using any apk then in settings select "Pre Launch Application". It should work then